# DropDown Select in Angular5 - Binding Object with NgModel doesnot update select value

Tags: select, angular5, ngmodel, angular-ngmodelchange

```
// html code   
 <select class="form-control form-control-primary" 
        (change)="changeValue(data)"
        [(ngModel)]="data" name="list" id="selectData">

          <option *ngFor="let data of dataList" [ngValue]="data">
           {{data.name}}
          </option>

    </select>

//  ts code
    data: any;
    dataList = [{id:1, name:"XYZ"},{id:2,name:"ABC"}];

    changeValue(data){
        console.log(data);     // prints selected data correctly
    }
```

This is sample code just to explain how I had used it in my project.
In my case dataList array comes from an API, a grid is displayed at bottom of drop-down which gets updated according to the selected data of dropdown. When other than first data is selected in drop-down and I call API for dataList again to refresh the list, I need the selected prevoius option in drop-down but instead it gets reset to first option.

And I compulsory need to bind object with ngModel Select. Even I tried with ngModelChange, event.target.value but nothing worked for me. I get correct value of data in console but select doesnot get updated.

Answer (score 2):

After receiving data from the server, write a loop on dataList and compare their Id with the previous one you selected. then bind the object to data

```
// Assume that you saved previousId in localStorage or 
// got it from the server or somewhere else
for (let i = 0; i < this.dataList.length; i++ ) {
    if ( this.dataList[i].id == previousId ) {
        this.data = this.dataList[i];
    }
}
```

I hope it helps you :)

Comment: This I tried previously only and it works but what is the use of ngModel here then? 

And moreover my array dataList has large number of data then is it ok to have a loop in on change event?

Comment: @Khush ngModel will bind the selected option to your model. But for the first time, you model should initialize with the selected option in dataList.

Comment: @Khush If you don't need whole the object, it is better to change ngValue to `[ngValue]="data.id"`, and ngModel to `[(ngModel)]="data.id"`. Then you should just set selected id to ngModel at first, and it does not need any loop. Use the whole data just inside `changeValue(data)`

Comment: No, I need whole object of project as other values are dependant on other attributes of project

Comment: @Khush  You can save the object in `localStorage`, and use it again, or take it from API if it is possible.

Comment: yes, that is one of the possible solution, but I was looking for solution which works just with ngModel with Select